# Variable `org-mobile-directory` must point to an existing directory. Multiplatform setup, howto

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I configured emacs org-mode on a Mac, working properly, having my org files and MobileOrg file within my DropBox folder ( ~/DropBox/ ), and detailed as follows:

```
;; Set to the location of your Org files on your local system
(setq org-directory "~/DropBox/org")
;; Set to the name of the file where new notes will be stored
(setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "~/DropBox/org/flagged.org")
;; Set to <your Dropbox root directory>/MobileOrg.
(setq org-mobile-directory "~/Dropbox/MobileOrg")
```

Now, I will like to get my emacs setup working properly on my Windows box. I have been able to get it working in terms of reading my .emacs file and emacs.d folder, shared through symlink configuration.

Everything seems to be working properly, except that when I  want to execute org-mobile-pull or org-mobile-push on Windows, I get the following error: ***"Variable `org-mobile-directory` must point to an existing directory "***

The problem seems to be that emacs isn't configured to read or point to the org-mobile directory , per the paths set in .emacs (eg. = "~/DropBox/ ...........").

I found some info on the web, which pointed to setting a parameter on .emacs so that it identified while running on Windows, that it should look into a directory structure.

Now, how should I accomplish this appropriately?

I found some examples of:

;;On Windows
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (progn
       (setq default-directory "C:\Usuarios/User/")
     )
)

But it doesn't seem to be doing the job.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: i suspect the ~/ way of writing a location on your home directory might be part of the issue here - windows wouldn't support that.

Comment: Thanks, should I define the paths for Windows and Mac separately? where could I learn more on this?

Comment: After doing an evaluation of  (expand-file-name "~/Dropbox/MobileOrg") , I am getting the correct path on my Windows machine, which is "c:/Users/User/Dropbox/MobileOrg" . Any hints, appreciated.